# Mysql to Sphinx query conversion

Tags: sphinx

how can i write this query on sphinx `select * from vehicle_details where make LIKE "%john%" OR id IN (1,2,3,4)`, can anyone help me? I've search a lot and i can't find the answer. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you really want to use sphinx, could perhaps make id into a fake keyword, so can use it in the MATCH, eg

```
sql_query = SELECT id, CONCAT('id',id) as _id, make, description FROM ...
```

Now you have a `id` based keyword you can match on.

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('(@make *john*) | (@_id id1|id2|id3|id4)')
```

---

But do read up on sphinx keyword matching, as sphinx by default only matches whole words, you need to enable part word matching with wildcards, (eg with min_infix_len) so you can get **close** to a simple LIKE %..% match (which doesnt take into account words)

Answer (score 0):

Actually pretty hard to do, becuase you mixing a string search (the `LIKE` which will be a `MATCH`) - with an attribute filter.

Would suggest two seperate queries, one to sphinx for the text filter. And the IN filter just do directly in database (mysql?). Merge the results in the application.